# TestCafe GitLab pipeline DNS failure

Tags: gitlab, testcafe, cicd

I'm stuck on this one hence wondering if someone could help.

The test scripts I've created are run with no problem locally. When I run them on Gitlab pipeline I get the following error:

```
Failed to find a DNS-record for the resource at "https://example.com/".
```

Have searched but couldn't find anything. Found it has something to do with proxy which I've tried to bypass using --proxy-bypass flag in the yaml script but the issue persist. Any idea?

Comment: Hi, it looks like your testing page cannot be loaded for some reason. First of all, make sure that this testing page is accessible from your target machine. If it is not available only via TestCafe, in order to give you additional advice, we need to reproduce the issue locally. Please share a simple working project illustrating the issue and describe exact steps to reproduce it.